# Encoding URL by Google static maps

Tags: google-maps

I created the URL for static maps, everything works, but now convert this link you can open the map in Google?That is  on my website there is a picture card, but in the form of links, similar to [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%22.%24full_address.%22&zoom=15&size=400x400%22.%24markers.%22&sensor=false%27%20/%3E). How now add a link to this image, so when you click on the image to the full Google maps? 
Advance, thanks!

Comment: In an English site, it's better to use English if you want to get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this (if I understood you) - depending on what is in `.$full_address.`:

```
<a href=http://maps.google.com/?q=".$full_address."><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=".$full_address."&zoom=15&size=400x400".$markers."&sensor=false' />"></a>
```

This will turn your static map image into a link to Google Maps.